# Apache Airflow scheduling with a time bound and triggering

Tags: celery, airflow

I'm using airflow with celery Executor. Now I'm planning to develop user interaction for a task to decide to select branch using BranchOperator in a DAG. Its working by running continuous loop to checking value in database. But I feel it is not the good way of approach. Is there any alternative to do this?

And I want to wait for this interaction up-to particular time otherwise I want to stop. Is it possible to do this in airflow? And if is possible then is the any possibility to change this time bound dynamically?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a BranchOperator for this. If you want to proceed in your dag based on some value in the db, you should use a Sensor. There are some off the shelf sensors in airflow and you could also look at some of those to create your own. Sensors basically poll for a certain criteria and timeout after a configurable period of time. From your question it seems this is exactly what you need.